# How to get data using jQuery api from grails folder?

Tags: jquery, grails

I have doman class Album and Photo. In my data base Album has: id, name and user_id and photo: id, album_id, name and type. When User login grails creates folder with name as username and saves pictures there (in web-app folder in grails NOT in database). Now I need to get those pictures with jQuery API in my web app. my API Controller looks like this:

```
def getAlbumsList(){
    def resultJSON = [:]

    try{
        int userId

        try{
            userId = params.int('userId')
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        def conn =  sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()
        def sql =  new Sql(conn)

        def albumList = sql.rows("SELECT ab.a_name, MAX(p.p_name) as p_name FROM album ab INNER JOIN photo p ON ab.id = p.album_id WHERE ab.user_id = ?", userId)
        sql.close()

        def albums = []
        for(album in albumList){
            albums << [albumName: album.a_name, lastPhoto: grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("album/" + album?.p_name + ".jpg")?.file?.absolutePath]
        }

        resultJSON = [msg: 1, albums: albums]

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        resultJSON = [msg: 0, ex: e.getMessage() +  " " + e?.getCause() ]
    }

    render resultJSON as JSON
}


/*
 * Get photos for user.
 *
 * <p>
 * @param userId        id of user
 *
 * <p>
 * @return [msg: 1, photos: (Photo url data)] or [msg: 0, ex: Exception description ]
 *
 * <p>
 * @see Photo
 * @see User
 *
 */
def getAlbumPhotosList(){
    def resultJSON

    try{
        int userId

        try{
            userId = params.int('userId')
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

        def conn =  sessionFactory.currentSession.connection()
        def sql =  new Sql(conn)

        def photosList =  sql.rows("SELECT p.p_name FROM album ab INNER JOIN photo p ON ab.id = p.album_id WHERE ab.user_id = ?", userId)
        def photos = []
        for(photo in photosList){
            photos << grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("album/" + photo?.p_name + ".jpg")?.file?.absolutePath
        }

        resultJSON = [msg: 1, photos: photos]
        sql.close()
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        resultJSON = [msg: 0, ex: e.getMessage() +  " " + e.getCause() ]
    }

    render resultJSON as JSON
}
```

}

Can I do that and how?
Thanks for the answer and sorry for my English

Comment: why do you have the native sql in your code?

Answer (score 1):

simply store the file-names or URLs in your Photo class, as you can never know, what data lands in your folder